# Django CustomUser Function

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I created a CustomUser as follows, however, I am not able to use the CustomUser functions in Views as I get the error message "get_first_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" when I call CustomUser.get_first_name().
I checked my settings.py and do import CustomUser, models as well as settings in the view file.
If you could help me here that would be awesome.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='first_name', max_length = 15)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='last_name', max_length = 15)
    organization = models.CharField(verbose_name="organization", max_length = 15, choices=ORGANIZATIONS)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # check this for login email purposes
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'organization']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_organization(self):
        return self.organization

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
class Dashboard(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "plot.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['plot'] = plots.plotsurvey()
        return context
```

plots.py

```
def plotsurvey():
    c = CustomUser()
    name = c.get_first_name()

    df = pd.read_csv(str(name) +'.csv') #

    trace = go.Bar(
        x = df['Y'],
        y = df['Z'], name = 'N'
    )
    data = [trace]
    layout = go.Layout(title="X", margin = dict(b = 150))


    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    plot_div = plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)
    #logger.info("Plotting number of points {}.".format(3))
    return plot_div
```

Comment: Can you add the code that is actually generating the error? As in when you actually use CustomUser?

Comment: But I suspect that you are using an instance method, as if it were a class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an instance method, as if it were a class method.

You need to change, this

```
def plotsurvey():
    c = CustomUser()
    name = CustomUser.get_first_name()
    ...
```

To this (use the instance)

```
def plotsurvey():
    c = CustomUser()
    name = c.get_first_name()
    ...
```

Note that you have another problem here. You are not actually getting any real user with `c = CustomUser()`. To get a user, you would need to do something like

```
CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

In that case, you finally get:

```
def plotsurvey(user_id):
    c = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    name = c.get_first_name()
    ...
```

### EDIT

We can be more practical, using the view.

```
class Dashboard(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "plot.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        context['plot'] = plots.plotsurvey(user.pk)

        return context
```

Comment: @ jhc thanks a lot, especially for the user_id one. Following up on this, could you also post the edited views.py i.e. adding the request/user_id to get it in the class based view? That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use request object

```
request.user.get_first_name()
```